# Convert values in string tuple returned by findall to int

Tags: regex, python-3.x, tuples, findall

I am reading unix directory list and want to extract file size, month, date , hour, min and file names using regex.

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jttoivon hyad-all    2356 Dec 11 11:50 add_colab_link.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 jttoivon hyad-all  164519 Dec 28 17:59 basics.ipynb
```

I am using findall and it works OK, except that it returns tuple with all strings. I want to convert store the integer values as int in the tuple. how do i do this?

```
def file_listing(filename="listing.txt"):

    list1=[]
    regex=re.compile("(\d+)\s(\w{3})\s+(\d{1,})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2})\s(\w*[.]?\w*)")

    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        for line in f:    # iterates through all the lines in the file
         list1.extend(regex.findall(line))
```

The code generates `('2356', 'Dec', '11', '11', '50', 'add_colab_link.py')` 
but what i need is  `(2356, 'Dec', 11, 11, 50, 'add_colab_link.py')` i.e. integer values as integers and not strings

Comment: Why are you parsing the output of `ls` instead of using filesystem functions that return the information directly?

Comment: Why are you using `findall()`? There should only be one match on each line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `int()` on the elements in the tuple that should be integers.

```
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        size, month, day, hour, minute, name = regex.search(line).groups()
        list1.append((int(size), month, int(day), int(hour), int(minute), name))
```